# Can't read output of httpservice

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, httpservice

I have an `HTTPservice`

```
id="myhttp"
url="site.com/script.php"
method="POST"
resultFormat="xml"
```

The script it uses returns

```
 $output = '<worked>' . $worked . '</worked>';
 echo $output;
```

Problem is when I try to read `worked`, it tells me the variable `worked` is not there

```
event.result.worked
myhttp.lastResult.worked
```

The only thing that works is using `toString()`

```
myhttp.lastResult.toString()
or event.result.toString()
```

What am I doing wrong?

- I plan to add other variables to the output `time`, so need to access each `time` and `worked` separately.
- I may also need to return multiple responses each with their own `worked` and `time` values. How do I do that. I was thinking to not use XML. Is there a more lightweight option. Flex shows I have the following options: `array` `e4x` `flashvars` `object` `text` `xml`

Comment: Is the XML that comes from the PHP script well formed? I don't see the actual <?xml ?> declaration. What's the output of event.result.toString()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use e4x as your return type. By declaring your return type as xml, you tell flex to handle it as an [XMLNode](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/xml/XMLNode.html), which is legacy and shouldn't be used.

If you need to use XMLNode for some unknown reason, you can get the value of the text by using event.result.nodeValue.

Answer (score 0):

Should your return type be e4x?